# Single login over multiple apps in jetty

Tags: authentication, jetty

I currently use jetty in my OSGi application. In this application I've created 2 webapps (in seperate bundles) with their own WEB_INF, to keep it easy AppA and AppB. In this case, AppA also includes the necessary jetty.xml file(s) to start the jetty server in the OSGi enviroment.

Now I wanted to add some authentication. I followed the documentation (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security.html#configuring-security-authentication) and added all necessary configs.

Jetty.xml;

```
<Call name="addBean">
<Arg>
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
    <Set name="name">Realm</Set>
    <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/auth.properties</Set>
    <Set name="refreshInterval">5</Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

Scince this is the only realm, all authentication services use it. when I deploy this, I indeed have a login option when I browse to url's that have a security constraint (in both apps). To be complete; I use the form login method, so a nice form is presented.

However, when I login in AppA, I'm not logged in in AppB. So when I go to localhost/appA/secured and I login I still have to login (with the same credentials) when I go to localhost/AppB/secured.

Now I was wondering if there is a possiblity to link both apps in such a way that when I login in appA I'm automaticly logged in in appB? I've noticed that in earlier versions there was a HashSSORealm, but in jetty 9 it doesn't seem present annymore.

Comment: Hi there, have you resolved your issue? I have similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791242/jetty-9-hashloginservice and not sure if you could help me out? tq. /d